# Mask HTML password input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do have an unusual request, I am working on an application where two persons have to enter a random number between 1 and 1000 in an `input[type=password]` on the same screen - now I am looking for a way to hide how many numbers have been entered into the password field, f.e.

- Person 1: 29 = **
- Person 2: 587 = ***

I am looking for a way to always show ****

Hope you guys get my question.

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE**

It looks like I was not able to describe what I "need" so here is an update with some pictures:

Person 1 enters the number 32, this will look like this:
[image: Number 32]

Person 2 enters the number 325, this will look like this: [image: Number 345]

My goal is that the input always looks like this: [image: Desired look]

I just want to change the look of the field, not the value.

Comment: you want to hide result of their password always with `*` ?

Comment: I want to make sure that no one can see what number has been entered - so the password field should always display the same amount of * or bullets

Comment: ok after enter the value if you show only three * , Suppose user enter 1234 instead 4 * you want show 3 *.Suppose you will achieve that, after that user wants to edit the value.What will happen then. You want to clear the values ?

Comment: How will user know how many values he has entered ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://jsfiddle.net/h4ftk86w/1/.I am not sure what exactly your requirement.

Comment: Using `input[type=password] { color: transparent; }` in CSS will hide the complete input (as long as the text in the input is not highlighted). No JavaScript necessary.

Comment: I updated my question with some pictures to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a pretty hacky css way not sure about browser support but no JavaScript needed!

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/QyoEKL)

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">
  <span>&middot;&middot;&middot;&middot;</span>
  <input type="password" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test{
  position:relative;
}
.test span{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  padding:5px; /** Match the input padding **/
  font-size:2em;
  line-height:.6em
}
input{
  z-index:0;
  text-indent:-9999px; /** Hide the text typed in **/
}
```

It's essentially just `absolute` positioning the dots over the input then hiding the text via `text-indent`

Comment: Your way gave me an idea, I created an image with the four bullets and used that as background image on my input's, that did the trick for me!

Comment: Glad to help. That way is actually much better haha mines a little overkill

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to update a state variable using the change event.
Here is an example with jquery. (And assuming always displaying 4 asterisks)

```
var entered = "";

$("#my-input").change(function() {
    var newVal = $("#my-input").val();
    if (newVal.length < 4) {
        //backspace was pressed
        entered = entered.substr(0, entered.length - 1);
    } else if (newVal.length > 4) {
        //another key was pressed
        entered += newVal.substr(4);
    }
    $("#my-input").val("****");
});

$("#my-input").val("****");
```

This isn't foolproof, it will break down if the user selects,copies,pastes. etc.

While this will get you the effect you asked for, as other comments hinted at, it may not be the best user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the CSS to make the text color same as the input field:

```
input[type=password] {
    color: white;
}
```

**Edit:** Or to be independent of input color like @GeraldSchneider commented:

```
input[type=password] {
    color: transparent;
}
```